# Smooth scrolling effect issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, smooth-scrolling

This is an add-on question from my previous post: [Smooth scrolling link effect issue with vertical menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54857742/smooth-scrolling-link-effect-issue-with-vertical-menu)

I'm revising a template https://codepen.io/eksch/pen/xwdOeK to fit with my site contents. The length of my sections will be way longer than how the template is designed. From the javascript, the smooth scrolling effect is closely related to the position of the browser and section divs, such that:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollDistance = $(window).scrollTop();

    // Show/hide menu on scroll
    //if (scrollDistance >= 850) {
    //      $('nav').fadeIn("fast");
    //} else {
    //      $('nav').fadeOut("fast");
    //}

    // Assign active class to nav links while scolling
    $('.page-section').each(function(i) {
            if ($(this).position().top - $(this).height() <= scrollDistance) {
                    $('.navigation a.active').removeClass('active');
                    $('.navigation a').eq(i).addClass('active');
            }
    });
}).scroll();
```

Is it possible to increase the length of the sections to be 100% or greater and still maintain the effect? ( the default length is not big enough for my contents)
I tried to adjust the last section div to 100% and the highlight effect stopped working, and there is a trailing white space after the div.

[image]

Trailing space:

[image]

I'm pretty new to front end, and I'd appricate for any suggestions or help on the issue.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you tryout the solution provided and give a response?

Comment: @PushkarAdhikari thank you fo the solution , I will test it out today if I do get to a computer. I will let you know no later than today .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with your CSS, and I think this is what you want.

```
// in .page-section
height: 90%;
width: 64%;
margin-left: 30%;
margin-top: 4%;

// in .navigation
margin-left: 0%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
```

you can check my updated [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JzPpRZ)

***Edit***

For it to

> work if the section length requires scrolling down

or to

> allow for contents that exceed the browser height

just change `height: 90%;` to `min-height: 90%;` in `.page-section`

check the CodePen above for the updated code.

Comment: Will this allow for contents that exceed the browser height? The example worked for 100% section hight will this still work if the section length requires scrolling down? Thank you so much!

Comment: I think it would. I haven't tried myself. so give me a little time to kinda get it tested.

Comment: @lydias please clarify one more thing: do you want the section to be internally scrollable for large text or accordingly expand in height?

Comment: I would prefer it to scroll just like a normal page on the right side while having the highlight stay on the section instead of having double scrolls for internal scrolling. Thank you! Let me know if that is possible.

Comment: Okay. I tried internal scroll, IMO its looks bad. normal scroll looks good and works.